# Создание суперюзера. Проблема

Tags: python, django

Я только учусь и пока не понимаю  в чем у меня проблема. Написал свою модель пользователя:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
"""Модель пользователя"""
first_name = models.CharField(
    verbose_name='Имя',
    max_length=50
)
last_name = models.CharField(
    verbose_name='Фамилия',
    max_length=50
)
middle_name = models.CharField(
    verbose_name='Отчество',
    max_length=50
)
phone_number = models.CharField(
    verbose_name='Номер телефона',
    max_length=20,
    unique=True
)
email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='Электронная почта',
    unique=True
)
company = models.ForeignKey(
    InsuranceCompany,
    verbose_name='Компания',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=True
)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(
    verbose_name='Дата создания учетной записи',
    auto_now_add=True
)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(
    default=True
)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(
    verbose_name='Администратор',
    default=False
)

objects = UserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Пользователь'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'
    ordering = ['-id']

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.first_name}{self.last_name}{self.middle_name}'
```

Так же написал свой Usermanager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
use_in_migrations = True

def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Необходимо указать адрес электронной почты')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
    
    return self._create_user(email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)
```

Но после создания суперюзера командой python manage.py createsuperuser не могу зайти в админку. Пишит что пароль и эмейл не правильный. Куда смотреть? Где я накосячил?

Comment: А прописать вашу модель в AUTH_USER_MODEL не забыли?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: В AUTH_USER_MODEL прописать не забыл)

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот так все работает

```
 USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
 REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

user manager

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email is Required')
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff = True')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser = True')

        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```